# Implement Facebook, Instagram, Google and Apple login on existing react app

Tags: react-native, facebook-php-sdk, react-native-instagram-login

Right now we have the only login with the phone number (we a reusing firebase).
We need to implement a login using those other platforms.
I am afraid to implements all sign-in functions. If you have the experience, please help me.

Comment: firebase provides these options but still you need to configure SDKs for each platform separately.

Comment: Should I config SDK for each social login?

Comment: Yes, you can read here more https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth

Comment: Thanks, many. Actually, I am a new ReactNative. Could you help me with my code?

Comment: Please visit our profile and reach us otherwise i am not sure what help you will need.

Answer (score 0):

**Facebook login in React Native apps**

Step 1: Create a basic React Native app

```
$ react-native init myApp
```

Step 2: Facebook Developer Console — Create your app

> The first thing we need to do is to create a new application in
> Facebook’s developer dashboard, and this app is the one that Facebook
> will use to ask our users for their permission when we try to log them
> into our React Native application.

[image]

> Once we finish creating our app, we will go to the Facebook app
> dashboard and pick App Id from there. It will be required in
> installing the Facebook plugin in the app

[image]

‌‌Step 3: Add your Platforms to Facebook

> We need to let Facebook know which platforms we’ll be using (if it’s
> just web, iOS, or Android).

[image]

> we just need the Bundle ID

[image]

‌Step 4: Install the React Native FBSDK to connect your app with Facebook

> Install JavaScript packages
> Install the react-native-fbsdk package: `yarn add react-native-fbsdk` or `npm install react-native-fbsdk` 
> Finally, link the SDK to configure the iOS and Android projects: `react-native link react-native-fbsdk`

Step 5: Running Apps
Step 6: Authenticate Users using Facebook

> Login

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';

export default class Login extends Component {
render() {
return (
<View>
<LoginButton
onLoginFinished={
(error, result) => {
if (error) {
console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
} else if (result.isCancelled) {
console.log("login is cancelled.");
} else {
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
(data) => {
console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
}
)
}
}
}
onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")}/>
</View>
);
}
};
```

> Requesting additional permissions with Login Manager

```
// ...

import { LoginManager } from "react-native-fbsdk";

// ...

// Attempt a login using the Facebook login dialog asking for default permissions.
LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
function(result) {
if (result.isCancelled) {
console.log("Login cancelled");
} else {
console.log(
"Login success with permissions: " +
result.grantedPermissions.toString()
);
}
},
function(error) {
console.log("Login fail with error: " + error);
}
);
```

[image]

> My App.js looks like following

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import LoginController from './LoginController';
const App = () => {return (<LoginController/>);};
export default App;
```

> Implement a Facebook login button

```
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
.....(inside render)
<LoginButton
onLoginFinished={
(error, result) => {
if (error) {
console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
} else if (result.isCancelled) {
console.log("login is cancelled.");
} else {
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
(data) => {
console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
}
)
}
}
}
onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")}/>
....
```

> LoginController.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, StatusBar, Button, Image, } from 'react-native';
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
export default class LoginController extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pushData: [],
            loggedIn: false
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
                <SafeAreaView>
                    <ScrollView
                        contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
                        style={styles.scrollView}>
                        {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
                            <View style={styles.engine}>
                                <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
                            </View>
                        )}
                        <View style={styles.body}>
                            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                                <LoginButton
                                    onLoginFinished={
                                        (error, result) => {
                                            if (error) {
                                                console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
                                            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                                                console.log("login is cancelled.");
                                            } else {

                                                console.log(result);
                                                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                                                    (data) => {
                                                        this.setState({
                                                            loggedIn: true,
                                                            userID: data.userID
                                                        })
                                                        console.log(data, data.accessToken.toString())
                                                    }
                                                )
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    onLogoutFinished={() =>
                                        this.setState({
                                            loggedIn: false,
                                            userID: ''
                                        })
                                    } />
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                                {!this.state.loggedIn && <Text>You are currently logged out</Text>}
                            </View>
                            {this.state.loggedIn && <View>
                                <View style={styles.listHeader}>
                                    <Text>User Info</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
                                    <Text style={styles.title}>ID</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.message}>{this.state.userID}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>}
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    scrollView: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    listHeader: {
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
        color: "#222",
        height: 44,
        padding: 12
    },
    detailContainer: {
        paddingHorizontal: 20
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        paddingTop: 10
    },
    message: {
        fontSize: 14,
        paddingBottom: 15,
        borderBottomColor: "#ccc",
        borderBottomWidth: 1
    },
    dp: {
        marginTop: 32,
        paddingHorizontal: 24,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    engine: {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: 0,
    },
    body: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    sectionContainer: {
        marginTop: 32,
        paddingHorizontal: 24,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        marginTop: 32,
        paddingHorizontal: 24,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    sectionTitle: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: '600',
        color: 'black',
    },
    sectionDescription: {
        marginTop: 8,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '400',
        color: 'black',
    },
    highlight: {
        fontWeight: '700',
    },
    footer: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: '600',
        padding: 4,
        paddingRight: 12,
        textAlign: 'right',
    },
});
```

Step 7: Test your app on Android

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: thanks for this fb login coding. how about ig, apple?